# Merge Replication Failed During Synchronization. After re-run the agent failed at with (Replication Agent FATAL ERROR and shutdown)

Tags: sql-server-2008, fatal-error, agent, merge-replication

In our corporation we configure a merge replication (PULL) as below:

```
Publisher : SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows 2003 Server

Subscriber: SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows 2003 Server (This is a instance sql)
```

We use scripts for Create/Change articles. We run these scripts on publisher and made snapshot.

After start replication agent, during synchronization it failed because of low connection speed.

Here is the failure log:

> 2012-02-25 06:00:25.184 Category:SQLSERVER Source:  TMCTS Number:  0
>   Message: Login timeout expired 2012-02-25 06:00:25.200
>   Category:SQLSERVER Source:  TMCTS Number:  0 Message: The merge
>   process failed to execute a query because the query timed out. If this
>   failure continues, increase the query timeout for the process. When
>   troubleshooting, restart the synchronization with verbose history
>   logging and specify an output file to which to write..

But, it downloaded some scripts and applied them. When we are trying to run it after, it will fail.

Here is the second log:

```
Step Name  Run agent.
Duration  00:05:48
Sql Severity  0
Sql Message ID  0
Operator Emailed  
Operator Net sent  
Operator Paged  
Retries Attempted  0

Message
2012-02-26 10:36:01.604 [3%] [1464 sec remaining] Preparing table 'BuyBillDocTimeLimit' for merge replication
2012-02-26 10:36:06.838 [3%] [1425 sec remaining] Applied script 'FundBuyBillDocdc7438bb_129.sch'
2012-02-26 10:36:07.010 [3%] [1425 sec remaining] Preparing table 'FundBuyBillDocTimeLimit' for merge replication
2012-02-26 10:36:12.354 [4%] [1370 sec remaining] Applied script 'FundBillDocTimeLimit_130.sch'
2012-02-26 10:36:12.541 [4%] [1370 sec remaining] Preparing table 'FundBillDocTimeLimit' for merge replication
2012-02-26 10:36:18.901 [4%] [1366 sec remaining] Applied script 'FPBillDocTimeLimit_131.sch'
2012-02-26 10:36:19.088 [4%] [1366 sec remaining] Preparing table 'FPBillDocTimeLimit' for merge replication
2012-02-26 10:36:23.307 [8%] [802 sec remaining] Bulk copying data into table 'sysmergesubsetfilters'
2012-02-26 10:36:32.307 [8%] [802 sec remaining] Bulk copied data into table 'sysmergesubsetfilters' (0 rows)
2012-02-26 10:36:32.822 [12%] [629 sec remaining] Bulk copying data into table 'sysmergesubsetfilters'
2012-02-26 10:36:34.588 [12%] [629 sec remaining] Bulk copied data into table 'sysmergesubsetfilters' (0 rows)
2012-02-26 10:36:34.885 [15%] [484 sec remaining] Bulk copying data into table 'sysmergesubsetfilters'
2012-02-26 10:36:37.276 [15%] [484 sec remaining] Bulk copied data into table 'sysmergesubsetfilters' (0 rows)
2012-02-26 10:36:37.541 [18%] [394 sec remaining] Bulk copying data into table 'sysmergesubsetfilters'
2012-02-26 10:36:39.729 [18%] [394 sec remaining] Bulk copied data into table 'sysmergesubsetfilters' (0 rows)
2012-02-26 10:36:39.994 [22%] [327 sec remaining] Bulk copying data into table 'sysmergesubsetfilters'
2012-02-26 10:36:41.791 [22%] [327 sec remaining] Bulk copied data into table 'sysmergesubsetfilters' (0 rows)
2012-02-26 10:36:42.072 [25%] [277 sec remaining] Bulk copying data into table 'sysmergesubsetfilters'
2012-02-26 10:36:43.932 [25%] [277 sec remaining] Bulk copied data into table 'sysmergesubsetfilters' (0 rows)
2012-02-26 10:36:44.229 [28%] [239 sec remaining] Bulk copying data into table 'sysmergesubsetfilters'
2012-02-26 10:36:46.166 [28%] [239 sec remaining] Bulk copied data into table 'sysmergesubsetfilters' (0 rows)
2012-02-26 10:36:48.775 [28%] [239 sec remaining] Applied script 'GoodsForcePack3fa76b46_125.dri'
2012-02-26 10:36:51.229 [29%] [245 sec remaining] Applied script 'GoodsForcePack3fa76b46_125.trg'
2012-02-26 10:36:53.854 [29%] [244 sec remaining] Applied script 'SalesOpenAccou99ea62c0_126.dri'
2012-02-26 10:36:56.541 [30%] [246 sec remaining] Applied script 'SalesOpenAccou99ea62c0_126.trg'
2012-02-26 10:36:59.354 [30%] [247 sec remaining] Applied script 'MasterCloseScenario_127.dri'
2012-02-26 10:37:02.072 [31%] [246 sec remaining] Applied script 'MasterCloseScenario_127.trg'
2012-02-26 10:37:05.135 [31%] [247 sec remaining] Applied script 'BuyBillDocTimeLimit_128.dri'
2012-02-26 10:37:07.822 [32%] [248 sec remaining] Applied script 'BuyBillDocTimeLimit_128.trg'
2012-02-26 10:37:12.041 [32%] [249 sec remaining] Applied script 'FundBuyBillDocdc7438bb_129.dri'
2012-02-26 10:37:15.244 [33%] [251 sec remaining] Applied script 'FundBuyBillDocdc7438bb_129.trg'
2012-02-26 10:37:18.275 [33%] [252 sec remaining] Applied script 'FundBillDocTimeLimit_130.dri'
2012-02-26 10:37:21.275 [34%] [252 sec remaining] Applied script 'FundBillDocTimeLimit_130.trg'
2012-02-26 10:37:25.213 [34%] [253 sec remaining] Applied script 'FPBillDocTimeLimit_131.dri'
2012-02-26 10:37:28.603 [35%] [255 sec remaining] Applied script 'FPBillDocTimeLimit_131.trg'
********************************************************************************
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Replication Agent

A replication agent encountered a fatal error and was shut down. A mini-dump has been generated at the following location:
```

How we can resume synchronization, skipping those user scripts which are already applied? (Resume synchronization after last script.)